# Recyclerview with custom GridlayoutManager android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am working on the custom layout of `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

which should looks like this

[image]

adapter.java

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfilePhotosViewHolder ProfilePhotosViewHolder, final int position) {

        model = list.get(position);


        if (position == 0) {
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getMeasuredHeight());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.getDrawingCache());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeBucket.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
        }

        if (position == 2) {
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.getMeasuredHeight());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.getDrawingCache());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowers.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        if (position == 5) {
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredHeight());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getDrawingCache());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        if (position == 7) {
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativePosts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredHeight());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getDrawingCache());
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageBitmap(b);
        }
        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setImageResource(model.photos);

        ProfilePhotosViewHolder.imgProfilePhotos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mMethods.showToast(mContext, "" + position);
            }
        });

    }
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_photos"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/im_profile_monuments" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_bucket"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_box"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_profile_bucket"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile_my_bucketlist" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_profile_bucket_count"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_profile_bucket"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="My"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium" />
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_profile_bucket_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_profile_bucket_count"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Bucket list"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium" />
        />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the custom layout which is converted to `Bitmap` to fit to fixed position is not aligned properly

[image]

Comment: remove `android:singleLine="true"` from your layout.

Comment: doesn't made any difference :(

Answer (score 0):

For keeping views square  in Recycler view:

to onBind function of ViewHolder I passed width of the column (it was calculated as screen size / number of columns) and inside ViewHolder was

```
itemView.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));
```

where itemView is ViewHolder view and width is column width. Of course you need FrameLayout to do that.

hope this helps.

cheers

EDIT: You can use

```
itemView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, width));
```

if parent is Relative Layout

Comment: should I make my custom RelativeLayout to FrameLayout ?

Comment: as i can see there is a constructor  `new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(int,int)` so you can try that :) sorry for missguide

Comment: The problem is if I fix the size of my RelativeLayout , the rest images in the grid gets adjusted according to the screen size , but my RelativeLayout would remain the same :(

Comment: your problem is probably this line `ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.layout(0, 0, ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredWidth(), ProfilePhotosViewHolder.relativeFollowing.getMeasuredHeight());` what does it do?